# How to properly use Stripe Customer API for Radar when not storing any customer information

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, stripe-payments, e-commerce

We use Stripe for customer purchases. We send their info off to stripe, get a token, pass that token to our backend and create a charge.

I'm trying to add a "Customer" object to the process to hopefully enhance the Radar fraud detection features on Stripe. Now I'm taking that token from the front-end and on the backend I look up customers with the "similar" matching name, email, and phone number, or create one if none exist.

If an exact match is found and only one result is returned I use that one, if there isn't an exact match I take all that are available and match all the fields provided by the customer with what Stripe gives me and "add up" the number of matching fields to try to find the "best one" that matches the best.

If it's a new Customer (to Stripe), I create the Customer and assign the payment token we received from the front-end to the customer's payment source and then create the charge as before but with the Customer now associated with the Charge.

If there was an existing Customer, I took whatever was the best match (or the only match) and "update" that Customer with whatever information the user has provided, and assign that token to their payment method.

We don't have customer or user accounts, we don't store any information about them other than their purchase. So we don't retain the Customer ID that Stripe gives us. So I have to search for it from stripe every time.

This is working just fine in testing/development, but it seems kinda weird to me to do it this way. Since I have to update the user (even if it's just their payment method/token) every single time, I wonder if that will make tracking purchases and fraud more difficult or less reliable if I'm constantly looking up users and updating their information (or even just payment source token).

```
    let stripeCustomer
    stripeCustomer = await stripe.findOrCreateCustomer(
      makeCustomerInfo(cart, params)
    )

    charge = await stripe.createCharge(
      makeChargeInfo({totals, cart, stripeCustomer, params})
    )


async findOrCreateCustomer(customerCreateParams) {
  let customer

  // First, try to find a Customer that matches the params that the user provided
  customer = await this.searchForCustomer(customerCreateParams)
  // If we found a customer, update it with the new params (such as payment token and any changes to address)
  if (customer && customer.id) {
    // CustomerUpdateParams and CustomerCreateParams have practically all the same fields,
    // so reuse the existing CustomerCreateParams object for CustomerUpdateParams
    customer = await this.client.customers.update(
      customer.id,
      customerCreateParams
    )
  }

  // If a Customer was not found, create a new one
  if (customer === undefined) {
    customer = await this.client.customers.create(customerCreateParams)
  }

  // Return whatever we found/updated/created
  return customer
}


async searchForCustomer(customerParams) {
  let customer
  // Define the basic query params (email, phone, name)
  const queryParams = [
    customerParams?.email ? `email~"${customerParams?.email}"` : '',
    customerParams?.phone ? `phone~"${customerParams?.phone}"` : '',
    customerParams?.name ? `name~"${customerParams?.name}"` : ''
  ].filter((p) => !!p)

  // Start with an 'AND' query and try to find an exact match to start
  let query = queryParams.join(' AND ')
  let searchResult
  searchResult = await this.client.customers.search({
    query
  })

  // If there were no results from the 'AND' query, try an 'OR' query to get more results
  if (!searchResult?.data?.length) {
    query = queryParams.join(' OR ')
    searchResult = await this.client.customers.search({
      query
    })
  }

  if (searchResult?.data?.length === 1) {
    // If we get exactly one result, take that one
    customer = searchResult?.data[0]
  } else if (searchResult?.data?.length > 1) {
    // If we get more than one result, attempt to find the "best" one.
    // The default limit is 10, we could potentially ask for more, but I'm worried about performance if we do.
    // It appears they're (usually?) sorted from newest to oldest.
    searchResult?.data?.forEach((searchResultCustomer) => {
      searchResultCustomer.score = buildScore(
        searchResultCustomer,
        customerParams
      )
      if (!customer || searchResultCustomer?.score > customer?.score) {
        customer = searchResultCustomer
      }
    })
  }

  return customer
}


async createCharge(chargeCreateParams) {
  return await this.client.charges.create(chargeCreateParams)
}
```

Comment: I recommend that you look at this, https://stripe.com/docs/radar/risk-evaluation. Their Radar evaluates the risk level for each payment in real time. I'm not sure what you're exactly asking in terms of Radar but you should talk to their support team if you have a more specific question. If you do not store any data on your end, as you scale, yes tracking could get challenging but your question is a bit vague. Also, they have rate limits, https://stripe.com/docs/rate-limits that you'd hit as you scale when you make GET requests to attain the Customer object.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.